# Espresso Android Test Fail - android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id:

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I have a test case to perform over a fragment which has a Dialog with edittext. So once i enter 4 numbers in the edittext the dialog closes and falls back to the fragment.

Im able to enter the numbers in the Dialog Edittext, but once i fall back to the below fragment after reaching 4 characters, the test is failing on the edittext id (which worked fine when entered 4 characters).

```
onView(withId(R.id.pin_hidden_edittext_settings)).perform(replaceText("2"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    pause();

    onView(withId(R.id.pin_hidden_edittext_settings)).perform(replaceText("22"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    pause();

    onView(withId(R.id.pin_hidden_edittext_settings)).perform(replaceText("222"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    pause();

    onView(withId(R.id.pin_hidden_edittext_settings)).perform(replaceText("2222"), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

after the 4th character the test fails at "pin_hidden_edittext_settings" giving the following error message:

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.mytest.sample:id/pin_hidden_edittext_settings

Thank you, please help me!